# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2} dx$$

Any hints?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-(x-1%2Fx)%5E2)+from+0+to+infinity), that integral is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106965/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-of-exp-x2-1-x2-on-0-infty

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. One may apply the following result, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{a}x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x  ,\qquad a>0,
$$ which is true for any integrable $f$  over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's the question about how to evaluate the integral

Comment: The above hint gives a clear way:$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2} dx=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2}dx =\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx. $$

Comment: @OlivierOloa That is a cool theorem - how do you prove that?

Comment: @WillCraig One may perform the change of variable $x=e^t$.

Comment: @WillCraig apply the same steps as I did in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Putting $u=x-1/x$, $x = \frac{1}{2}u+\sqrt{4+u^2} $ so $dx = \left( 1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+4}} \right)\frac{du}{2} $. The interval of integration changes to $(-\infty,\infty)$, so you have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\left( 1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+4}} \right)\frac{du}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \, du $$
since the second term is odd and hence has integral zero. Of course, we know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \, du=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{1}{y}$ :
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2}dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-(\frac{1}{y}-y)^2}\frac{dy}{y^2}$$
$t =x-\frac{1}{x}, dt =(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx $ :
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2}dx = \frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac{1}{x})^2}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: As Olivier Oloa mentioned, it works the same way with $\int_0^\infty f(x-\frac{1}{x}) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)dt$